# redirect to magento admin module from payapl

Tags: magento, redirect, paypal, customization, vendor

i have create a custom module for pay vendor's commission in magento admin. I am using paypal form with return url ***hostname/magento/index.php/vender/adminhtml_commision/pay/id/4/key/6qaGSxQ1ICrEtZXkVCw*** .

After success payment page is redirecting to magento admin dashboard while it should be redirect to my module page.

page is redirecting to my custom module page with status 302 and open magento dashboard.

The response header of the return url :

```
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 15 May 2014 13:28:22 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Location    http://localhost/topplefiable/index.php/admin/dashboard/
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.19
Set-Cookie  adminhtml=foitk9bk5p7qd25sh9ead2c9e7; expires=Thu, 15-May-2014 14:28:25 GMT; path=/topplefiable; domain=localhost; httponly
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.19
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  store=s_1396871408storeview; adminhtml=foitk9bk5p7qd25sh9ead2c9e7; __ar_v4=%7C44OQLIKYJZGCJOP7YJWKBT%3A20140326%3A1%7CU4JSAS7TBVBWZGNKUMAMLP%3A20140326%3A1%7CWULQ7VIZHNEFTE7AHVGV7R%3A20140326%3A1; __zlcmid=OhdjUktCqwpH3c
Host    localhost
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length  1037
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**Post response :**

```
address_city    WESLEY CHAPEL
address_country United States
address_country_code    US
address_name    RAYOMOND CHINOY
address_state   FL
address_status  confirmed
address_street  30310 HATZ WAY
address_zip 33543
auth    AVkSV2ZSf5ipfxTbeKzKz86hJLe00dVdfxCNrqCuR2pWDjbyC6eIPYoZM3ibYe85vdBQXvoikxWM96Fsdwls8oQ
business    stripa_1307688220_biz@domain.com
charset windows-1252
custom  
first_name  skumar
handling_amount 0.00
item_name   
item_number 
last_name   kumar
mc_currency USD
mc_fee  0.20
mc_gross    0.20
notify_version  3.8
payer_email asah_1314106743_per@domain.com
payer_id    Z95WWBMAGSL6Y
payer_status    verified
payment_date    06:27:47 May 15, 2014 PDT
payment_fee 0.20
payment_gross   0.20
payment_status  Completed
payment_type    instant
protection_eligibility  Eligible
quantity    1
receiver_email  stripa_1307688220_biz@domain.com
receiver_id SNQXFDAY5XY4G
residence_country   US
shipping    0.00
tax 0.00
test_ipn    1
transaction_subject 
txn_id  3T8615219R228771W
txn_type    web_accept
verify_sign A5aQCVrF8.8eOdu1dA6dqFof.9f4AfUbaoQLdRI9ETV8EbisVo3-1RdB
```

Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Comment: i am also trying another way, as we know that magento creates key for their admin url so redirect success response to frontend controller then redirect it to mageto admin url with last key value, but it still not working, it opens the dashboard..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after debugging errors, There was magento secrete key problem.

Magnto creates a key for each url, when we are passing "key" to paypal request it does not return "key" parameter.

Solution : Rename "key" to "magentokey" in paypal response, after success payment get "magentokey" and save paypal response in your database record. Then redirect to your custom form with "magentokey".